# How do you make a Horizontal Number Picker Widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I want to make a horizontal number picker as shown in the image below:
[image: Image Horizontal Picker]

I tried using horizontal listview and pageview widgets but couldn't do it. I've even tried using some GitHub addons such as NumberPicker and Carousel but they don't show the number's on the side.

Thank you!

Comment: you have to show some code that you have tried, and then someone helps you. No one  there write the whole code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into [this] : https://github.com/andrezanna/NumberPicker

This has all type of number picker.

Answer (score 2):

In [NumberPicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker#-readme-tab-) you can see the sample code

example:

```
      new NumberPicker.integer(
                initialValue: _currentValue,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100,
                onChanged: (newValue) =>
                    setState(() => _currentValue = newValue)),
            new Text("Current number: $_currentValue"),
```

Just Change `NumberPicker.Integer` into `NumberPicker.horizontal` and it will work.